# cakephp: running diffrent cakephp verison on same domain

Tags: php, cakephp

I have already installed cakephp verion 1.3 on root of domain for Application1.

Now i want to develop another music application, that i want to store in a sub-directory. Now i want to use latest cakephp version for this application.
I am new to cakephp, and donot want to use same cakephp core for both application. First root application was not developed by me.

Directory structure is a s follow.

```
ROOT
├── .htaccess
├── cake
│   ├── config
│   ├── console
│   ├── libs
│   ├── tests
├── app
│   │   ├── .htaccess
│   │   ├── libs
│   │   ├── vendors
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── plugins
│   │   ├── views
│   │   ├── models
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── temp
│   │   ├── WEBROOT
│   │   │   ├── .htaccess
├──music  (this one i want to use for latest version cakephp installation).
```

I installed cakephp 2.5.2 in music directory, but unable to access this by www.example.com/music/

It redirect to first root application i.e. example.com/member/index.
In

```
├── app
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├   ├──routes.php
```

I have this:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'index'));
```

If unable to understand what i want:

My Question:

> How can i run two different cakephp version, one on root of the domain
>   and second in subdirectory (music).

If not possible i will use same version, but one application will be in music sub directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the versions should work fine, just make sure you have not written a htaaccess rule to redirect all incoming request to the first cakephp folder.

Comment: My htaccess on root was: RewriteBase /~wkcdev/
   
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L] 
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]                            I  remove these rules and it works fine.